# jQuery .bind('show') not working appropriately when element is shown via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a snippet in my project similar to the one seen below:

```
$('#field').change(function() {
  var thisCondition = $(this).val();

  if(thisCondition) {
    $('#this_container').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

The above snippet is working.  When `thisCondition` evaluates to `true`, the container does fade in.  However, I also have the snippet below that is not functioning as expected.  It binds to `show` so that when the container fades in an event will be triggered:

```
$('#this_container').bind('show', function() {
  $.ajax({
     ...
  });
});
```

Shouldn't the snippet above react to line 5 in the `change` event handler?  Why is the `bind` method not triggering?

Comment: Are you sure that the `show` event is ever triggered by `fadeIn()`? I don't think so..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed that `show` is not a valid nor jQuery-triggered event.

**But** you can trigger it yourself! 
Try something like this :

`$('#this_container').fadeIn("slow", function() {
        $(this).trigger("show");
    });`

Answer (score 0):

The `show` is not a valid event, neither is triggered by jQuery. You need to construct your script in a different way altogether:

```
$('#field').change(function() {
  var thisCondition = $(this).val();

  if(thisCondition) {
    $.ajax({
      success: function () {
        $('#this_container').fadeIn();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

So, you can try to bring the AJAX content, and upon a successful request, you can show the container.

Comment: @Noah Can you please create a snippet of the same? What problem exactly are you facing?

Comment: The change isn't being recognized.  $('#field').change(function() { console.log('triggered'); }); But nothing in the console

Comment: @Noah What's the `#field` here? This could be possible only if it is an `input` or a `select`. Can you share the HTML, please.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
 $('#this_container').fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
      $.ajax({
        ...
       });
  });
```